# Como fazer uma ViewBag.lista receber um tipo List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Como eu devo fazer para passar uma lista (`List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`) para *view* por `ViewBag`?

Meu código:

```
string grupo = "ConfigsPortalWebTextos";
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> lista = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
var configuracoes = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection(grupo);
if (configuracoes != null && configuracoes.Count > 0)
{
   foreach (string key in configuracoes.AllKeys)
   {
      var teste = configuracoes[key];
       lista.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, configuracoes[key]));
   }
}

ViewBag.WebConfigPermissao = lista;
```

```
@ViewBag.WebConfigPermissao["Cadastro"]
```

**Erro**:

> A melhor correspondência de método sobrecarregado        `System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>>.this[int]` tem alguns argumentos inválidos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para tal recuperação na View, como ela tem um tipo definido, você da um [CAST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173105.aspx) para o especificado tipo que ai você consegue trabalhar de maneira ideal com os elementos dessa `List` de `KeyValuePair`.

Com essa lista seria assim:

***1 ) List***

*No código*

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> lista = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    lista.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("item1", "value1"));
    lista.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("item2", "value2"));

    ViewBag.WebConfigPermissao = lista;


    return View();
}
```

*Na View*

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> lista = (List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>)ViewBag.WebConfigPermissao;
}
@foreach (var item in lista)
{
    @item.Key @item.Value
}
```

*Pegar valor com [**Linq**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397906.aspx) dependendo da chave*

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> lista = (List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>)ViewBag.WebConfigPermissao;

    string value = "";
    KeyValuePair<string, string> saida;
    saida = lista.ToList().Where(x => x.Key == "item1").FirstOrDefault();
    if (saida.Key != null && saida.Value != null)
    {
        value = saida.Value;
    }    
}
```

---

***2 ) [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (recomendo)***

*No código:*

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> lista = new Dictionary<string, string>();            
    lista.Add("item1", "value1");
    lista.Add("item2", "value2");

    ViewBag.WebConfigPermissao = lista;


    return View();
}
```

*Na View*

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    Dictionary<string, string> lista = (Dictionary<string, string>)ViewBag.WebConfigPermissao;
}

@foreach (var item in lista)
{
    @item.Key @item.Value
}
```

*Pegar valor conforme chave*

```
String saida;
lista.TryGetValue("item1", out saida);
```

*Referencias:*

- [Conversões cast e conversões de tipo (Guia de Programação em C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms173105.aspx)
- [Introdução a consultas LINQ (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397906.aspx)
- [Classe Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Quick Tips : Usando o dictionary no C#](http://www.devmedia.com.br/quick-tips-usando-o-dictionary-no-c/15172)
- [C# List](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list)